# How to delete Outlook email account from Microsoft account?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft

I created a [Proton](https://proton.me/mail) email account some time ago, and since then I've been using it as my only email. These days I ended up needing to create a new Microsoft account, and I did so using the existing Proton email address. After this process I realized that a new Outlook email address had been automatically created for this account, even though I had created it using an existing email. From what I could understand, this address is considered an alias, or something like that, and it is prefixed with `outlook_` followed by a random string.

As much as I believe that the automatic creation of these emails is the standard operation when creating a Microsoft account, I find it annoying to have to worry about more than one email, so I wouldn't want to have it. Is there a way to delete or at least disable this email from Outlook, or is ignoring it the best I can do?

Comment: Per the [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-com-email-account-appears-as-outlook-long-series-of-letters-and-numbers-outlook-com-in-outlook-for-windows-90ed7938-7f21-4cb5-a69d-a3b79ea4eafd) referenced in  [@Arko's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1760658/1007040) it is not necessary and will cause problems if not removed.  If you can't delete the account normally, the same article explains how to remove the profile under **WORKAROUND**

Comment: @BlindSpots Could you clarify if you are talking about the first workaround that recommends setting up a manual IMAP/POP account?

Comment: Yes, if you want to setup one of your existing accounts in Outlook.  Alternatively (I assume) you can simply delete the existing profile and set webmail or another app as the default mail client.  The OS wants an email mechanism as default so it knows what to do when you click a `mailto` type link although even that likely isn't necessary but in its absence might trigger a mail setup wizard every time a send email type process is triggered.

Comment: I don't think the question is about the Outlook application. To my understanding if you create an outlook account online using third-party credentials, and then if you visit [Outlook](https://outlook.live.com/mail/0) it shows the weird alias. And that is why I recommended the second workaround in my answer.

Comment: Could this be more likely to find an acceptable answer on WebApps? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, the issue is explained here.

[Issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-com-email-account-appears-as-outlook-long-series-of-letters-and-numbers-outlook-com-in-outlook-for-windows-90ed7938-7f21-4cb5-a69d-a3b79ea4eafd)

> After adding an email account to Outlook for Windows (Outlook 2016, 2013, 2010 versions) you may experience the following:

> Your email account name shows up as outlook_[long series of letters and numbers]@outlook.com in the Folder Pane and when composing emails using Outlook for Windows.

> Recipients will also receive the email from the sender with the outlook_[long series of letters and numbers]@outlook.com format.

> When recipients reply to the email, the email bounces and you may receive the message “Undeliverable message when you send Internet mail in Outlook.”

This issue can occur when you register a 3rd party email address (e.g., an email address that is not Outlook.com or Hotmail.com) for your Microsoft Account and don't use Outlook.com for sending and receiving email.

The first workaround is to set up a manual IMAP/POP account in Outlook for Windows. But if you are going to be using the Outlook account anyway, you could just set up an email with an @outlook/hotmail.com extension as the primary alias and the way to do that is described here.

1. Visit this link -
   [Manage how you sign in to Microsoft](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=842796)
2. Under Add an alias, do one of the following:

   - Create a new Outlook.com email address and add it as an alias.
   - Add an existing email address as an alias.
3. Under Account aliases, select **Make primary** next to the email address that you want to use as your primary alias.

I did not find anything related to just removing that alias and to my understanding, Microsoft requires an alias and it cannot just be your ProtonMail id. You will find same suggestions as mine if you visit this link.

[Suggestions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-email-is-random-numbers-and-letters-how-do/06918bbc-8186-4b4c-a388-a91dfb7685bb)

Here is the detailed post by Microsoft. 
[Add or remove email alias](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-an-email-alias-in-outlook-com-459b1989-356d-40fa-a689-8f285b13f1f2?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: You reccomended creating an Outlook.com account without providing any supporting information.  Why is this reccomended?

Comment: Well, @Arko, even understanding the facts and reasons after your answer, this behavior is somewhat inconvenient, since, in theory, I didn't choose the option to create an email, but to use an existing one. Anyway, I'll take it. Thank you very much!